# How can i solve this problem using pointer in c?

Tags: c, function, pointers

can i solve this problem using pointers, and if so, how to do it?I solved it with just function using..Problem is :**Write a function that returns the sum and product of digits of some number**

```
#include <stdio.h>

/*  function:   sumDigits
    to calculate sum of all digits.
*/

int sumDigits(int num)
{
    int sum=0,rem;
    while(num > 0)
    {
        rem=num%10;
        sum+=rem;
        num=num/10;
    }

    return sum;
}

/*  function:   proDigits
    to calculate product of all digits.
*/

int proDigits(int num)
{
    int pro=1,rem;
    while(num > 0)
    {
        rem=num%10;
        pro*=rem;
        num=num/10;
    }

    return pro;

}
int main()
{
    int n;
    printf("\nEnter an integer number :");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    printf("\nSUM of all Digits is : %d",sumDigits(n));
    printf("\nPRODUCT of all digits: %d",proDigits(n));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: can you ? probably. *should* you ? I see zero reason whatsoever to do so.

Comment: i am just trying to learn pointers..if you or anyone can give it a try and help,i will be thankful

Comment: Are you supposed to write a *single* function to calculate both the sum and product? Maybe they want you to pass pointers for the results to be written into. But that's just a guess as you aren't actually returning any value in that case.

Comment: Yes, i need to write a function to calculate both

Comment: That qualifier makes a *big* difference. Rather than calculate-and-return, you're calculating and *setting* (the output arguments receiving the results). And yes, that could be done with  three arguments (the input value, and two output values delivered via formal parameters that are pointers to data, and summarily utilized within the function in doing so). Fyi, a `struct` with two members could also be used (and thus avoid pointer arguments again, as the original code has done).

Comment: Sorry i think here is some misunderstanding...this is how the originally form of problem was:Write a function that returns the sum and product of digits of some number

Comment: I strongly suspect that you are missing the point of the exercise if you use scanf to convert the input to an int.  Instead, you should be parsing the input stream yourself.

Comment: By my count, the program you show uses pointers in 7 locations.  I am almost certainly undercounting.  So you're already done!